# Median and Mode estimations in the QGIS Modeler?

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics, qgis-modeler

I would like to know if there is anyway in which I can combine the available tools in QGIS in the Modeler to estimate median and mode values from a raster (DEM) using polygons.

I know the zonal stats tool will calculate a few things, but not median and mode. There is a [plugin option](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59238/is-there-a-zonal-statistics-tool-to-calculate-median-and-mode-raster-values-for), but third-party plugins are not really well-looked upon at my work, so I'd prefer a different solution, and I'd be happy to try new suggestions. So, is there a way to use the built-in tools of QGIS in the Modeler to estimate median and mode values from a DEM using polygons?