# Vector to Raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I have been able to import a csv file into QGIS creating a vector file. I would like to convert the vector file into a raster file. An image of the vector file is shown below.

[image]

The structure of the file is shown below.

[image]

I used v.to.rast to try and convert the vector file to raster. I used the raw magnetics as the source of attribute values.

[image]

The following image was produce.

[image]
[image]

I am trying to reproduce an image like below in QGIS but not sure if there are limitations to QGIS that I am not aware of.

[image]

Are there settings in symbology which i am not aware of which could clean up the image.

[image]

I have been able to tidy up the image using hillsade see images below , however i am not yet able to get the desired result. Im trying to accentuate the magnetic anomalies in the image.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the problem is not the north south lines , the problem is tidying up the image so it more clear. similar to the image below my image with the north south lines

Comment: I have update the above post using hillside shading to produce a slightly clearer image

Comment: Hello BERA thanks for the help, I have added another image above to the left is the raster I have generated in qgis, to the right is an open source magnetic anomaly map. When I say 'tidy up' I am referring to enhancing the anomalies so they are more noticeable.  Hillshade had some desired effect. do you know of any other filter techniques i could use? thanks

Comment: It looks like you are trying to visualize earth magnetic data, total field measurements. for that I would recommand to do some processing steps before, like computing a kind of pseudo gradient. this can be achieved with the median computation of your data, search for "zonal statistics": https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59238/is-there-a-zonal-statistics-tool-to-calculate-median-and-mode-raster-values-for

Comment: Hi Bera how can I share my csv file with you?

Comment: You need to do microleveling before converting the point data set to a raster format.