# QGIS Python script for zonal statistics not running

Tags: pyqgis, zonal-statistics

I got this Python script from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45284/how-to-use-qgis-zonal-stats-plugin-from-python-console) previous post. I've edited it for my project but nothing happens when I execute it. I downloaded the zonal statistics plugin, and usually when I run it, it adds a new field to the shapefile with the statistics I need, for example minimum. Since I need to do it multiple times, I was hoping to use the script. I tried the batch execute, but for GDAL it doesn't allow you to select one statistic, and Saga always gives an error somewhere.

Here's the script I use:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.analysis import QgsZonalStatistics


#specify polygon shapefile vector
polygonLayer = QgsVectorLayer('D:/all_structures_tez.shp', 'zonepolygons', "ogr") 

# specify raster filename
rasterFilePath = 'D:/slow.tif'

# usage - QgsZonalStatistics (QgsVectorLayer *polygonLayer, const QString &rasterFile, const QString &attributePrefix="", int rasterBand=1)
zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics (polygonLayer, rasterFilePath, 'pre-', 1, QgsZonalStatistics.Min)
zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
```

QGIS ver 2.18.3

Comment: The code runs fine for me. When you open `all_structures_tez` after running it, there are no added columns, right?

Comment: hi! exactly..after running the script, i don't see any added columns. I also saved the script and execute it from the toolbox, but nothing.

Comment: Do you have the shp loaded in QGIS and are just checking the attribute table after running the script? I have to reload the shp to Q after running the code in order to see the attributes (i.e., it doesn't update the layer immediately).

Comment: @JeffLegitime try also to set the layer in _edit_ mode before running the script...

Comment: @mgri  thank you! After putting it in edit mode it worked! Please put your comment as answer to give you credit.

Comment: @JeffLegitime done, I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I performed a quick test and it seems that you need to turn on the *edit* mode for obtaining the desired result.

If you want to use Python for this, try to use the following code:

```
polygonLayer.startEditing() 
# usage - QgsZonalStatistics (QgsVectorLayer *polygonLayer, const QString &rasterFile, const QString &attributePrefix="", int rasterBand=1)
zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics (polygonLayer, rasterFilePath, 'pre-', 1, QgsZonalStatistics.Min)
zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
polygonLayer.commitChanges()
```